# Появление блока в области видимости?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Так как не владею информацией , хотелось бы получить информацию от и до , как действовать на DIV при прокрутки в центр ?

Конкретных примеров нету , точнее то что я делал оказалось ерундой !

**Не интересует** готовое решение но требуется грамотное разъяснение с примером здесь 
Лучший ответ будет вознаграждён через 2 дня 200 балами за труды , конкурс будет объявлен

Уважаемые специалисты поясните как это работает ?

```js
var $win = $(window);
var $marker = $('#marker');
$win.scroll(function() {
  if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() >= $marker.offset().top) {
    $win.unbind('scroll'); // load there 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Это взято с тостер и не работало 
и таких приеров из сети 11 пробовал

Comment: Возможно, стоит почитать о [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: Я пробовал читать но ни чего не понял

Comment: Это, однако, не причина выбрасывать отличный инструмент.

Comment: Я изучают его , скажи почему ты не ответил на вопрос ?

Comment: Не захотел, бывает.

Comment: а я твоего ответа ждал - если честно

Comment: Ответ, данный ниже, неплохо объяснил как и почему. Не будь его, я, вероятно, ответил бы. Если что-то неясно - задавайте вопросы, будем рады помочь :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вашем примере нет html разметки, поэтому работать он не может, а работает это так:

Складываем значение прокрутки страницы `$win.scrollTop()` и высоту окна `$win.height()`, этим мы получаем положение страницы относительно нижней границы окна, так как нам нужно узнать пересек ли элемент нижнюю границу окна, чтобы узнать стал ли он виден, потом проверяем, если это значение больше, чем отступ нужного элемента от верха страницы `$marker.offset().top`, то значит элемент уже появился внизу окна, соответственно виден.

```js
var $win = $(window);
var $marker = $('#marker');

//отслеживаем событие прокрутки страницы
$win.scroll(function() {
  //Складываем значение прокрутки страницы и высоту окна, этим мы получаем положение страницы относительно нижней границы окна, потом проверяем, если это значение больше, чем отступ нужного элемента от верха страницы, то значит элемент уже появился внизу окна, соответственно виден
  if($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() >= $marker.offset().top) {
    $('#message').html('виден'); //выполняем действия если элемент виден
  }else{
    $('#message').html('не виден'); //выполняем действия если не элемент виден
  }
});
```

```css
#marker{
  margin-top: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#message{
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="marker"></div>
```

Comment: @Geyan, На так посчитай координаты центра экрана и сравнивай с ними, а не с нижним краем

Comment: @Geyan вместо высоты экрана возьмите половину высоты и получите середину экрана, а не нижний край, это же логично)

Comment: @Geyan ну так я же ответил, вместо `$win.height()` используйте `$win.height()/2`, так вы получите середину экрана, а не нижний край